# How to trigger the :active pseudoclass on keyboard 'enter' press? (using only CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accessibility

**The CSS:**

```
a:focus  { opacity: .75 }
a:active { transform: translateY(4px) }
```

**The intent:**

1. Keyboard users tab to the link, using the `:focus` style as a visual cue
2. They hit `enter` to activate the link; the `:active` style gives visual keypress feedback

**The problem:**

The `:active` style triggers properly for a mouse click, but not a keypress. Can I fix this with just CSS?

Comment: You will need to share the code where you are trying to fix this issue for other users to effectively help you.

Comment: The :active CSS pseudo-class matches when an element is being activated by the user. It allows the page to give a feedback that the activation has been detected by the browser. When interacting with a mouse, this is typically the time between the user presses the mouse button and releases it. The :active pseudo-class is also typically_matched when using the keyboard tab key. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aactive

Comment: @J0e3gan My bad, I edited for clarity

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Good question!

Yeah, you can't do this anymore.

A long time ago MSIE treated `:active` like `:focus` so there was sort of a way to accomplish this with hyperlinks (this was before gigabit internet speeds and when browsers didn't do a good job of showing load-in-progress except for a dumb waving flag or something).

Run the below Snippet to see the behavior in action:

- `input type='button'` can be activated with `ENTER` or `SPACE`
- Holding down `SPACE` on a button will show the `:active` style (except for FireFox; this looks like FF bug since it works OK for mousedown)
- Holding down `ENTER` on a button will repeatedly trigger `onclick` every time your keyboard sends the character.
- Holding down `SPACE` on a button will trigger `onclick` only if the `SPACE` key is released while still focused on the button. (For example, you can simulate mouse click this way: tab to a button, hold down space, then hit tab again and release it to cancel the click.)
- Hyperlinks can be activated with `ENTER` only.
- Clicking on hyperlinks will show `:active` style, using `ENTER` (or touch) will not.

```js
document.getElementById('t1').focus(); // set focus for easier demo
```

```css
:active
{
   color: Red;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='t1' value='Set focus and hit tab'/>
<a href='javascript:;' onclick='console.log("Hyperlink")'>Hyperlink</a>
<input type='button' value='Button' onclick='console.log("Button")'/>
```

So you are stuck using JavaScript or a plugin like Flash / Silverlight for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely get `:focus` to work with keyboard, however active would be bit difficult.

`:focus` is applied when that element receives focus. Like, when user clicks an input field by mouse or selects that input field by tab. Here is an example that shows how focus work; both with tab and mouse. [W3School Focus](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_focus) For more info [MDN :focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afocus)

However `:active` is bit different. it gets applied in the timeline between user clicking the mouse button and releasing it. This is hard to achieve using keyboard. Because there is no press and hold for enter key. The moment user presses the enter button, link will open up. Here you can see the example on how `:active` works. [W3School Active](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_active) For more info [MDN :active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aactive)

If you are going to use the pseudo-classes for links, then I would suggest using `:focus`, it will do the trick for both mouse and tab key.

Comment: I added `.button:focus` to `transform` css style and seems to work fine with tab. Can you check? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgwrLtbh/)

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the effect that I wanted. I don't want the `transform` to apply when focusing via tab.

Answer (score 1):

:focus will be the state entered when the keyboard user tabs to that element. Note that tabbing will cycle through the link tags on your page, so any css styling must be applied with the selector a:focus.

:active will be the state entered when the user hits the enter button on their keyboard.

Here's a little snippet of an example of how to apply css for both keyboard and mouse users:

```
a:hover .class,
a:focus .class { 
  background-color: rgba(243,113,89, 0.95); 
}
```