# button:active is not applied when form is submitted

Tags: html, css, forms, onsubmit

I've got following situation.

A simple form with two fields and a submit button. Submit button was styled using `:active` pseudo-class and becomes red whenever pressed.

But it only works if button is clicked directly or the `Space` key is pressed (only in Chrome) when the button has focus.

However when the form is submitted using Enter key the button doesn't get its "active" state. Even if the button has focus and you press `Enter` it won't be styled.

Here an example:

```js
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += "Form submitted<br/>" ;
   
  return false;
});

buttonClick = function() {
  document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += "Button clicked<br/>" ;
}
```

```css
button {
  background: yellow;
}

button:active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" >
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" onclick="buttonClick()">Submit</button>
  <br><br>
  <div id="log"></div>  
</form>
```

One could say that's because actually the form is submitted without the button being pressed. But it's not true, you can submit the form any way you like the click event on the button itself will still fire.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Note: `<input type="submit">` and `<button type="submit"></button>` behave the same in this case

Comment: Note: On systems with multi-button mice, CSS 3 specifies that the :active pseudo-class must only apply to the primary button; on right-handed mice, this is typically the leftmost button. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Comment: `active` is only ...well *active* while *mousedown* meaning the time between  the user initiating pressing the mouse button down and the time when that mouse button is released. Keydown is a different event based on the user's time pressing down a key. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32485497/2813224

Comment: @floor In my interpretation CSS Level 3 spec (section 6.6.1.2) only says that non-primary mouse buttons must not activate the button and does not forbid other ways to do it even if you have a mouse: "On systems with more than one mouse button, :active applies only to the primary or primary activation button (typically the "left" mouse button), and any aliases thereof." (https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#useraction-pseudos) But clearly Firefox does it exactly like you cited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be sure that the `active` state/class is used try this:

```
button.active, button:active {
    // your code goes here
}
```

And try to add this in your `buttonClick` function (`this` is the button element) - and jQuery is used.

```
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

I also recognized a issue that you can fire the submit button multiple times, try to disable the button on the first click if you don't want that with the following:

```
onclick="this.disabled = true;"
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like doing it by hand is the only solution.